# codeception with chromediver - Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: php, yii, yii2, selenium-chromedriver, codeception

I try run acceptance tests.

**acceptance.suite.yml**

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
      - WebDriver:
            url: 'http://localhost/'
            window_size: false # disabled in ChromeDriver
            port: 9515
            browser: chrome
      - \Helper\Acceptance        
    config:
```

next I run chromedriver:

```
vagrant@homestead:/usr/local/bin$ chromedriver --url-base=/wd/hub
Starting ChromeDriver 2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
```

next, i run Xvfb:

```
Xvfb :0 -ac -screen 0 1280x960x24 &
```

And finally i start tests:

```
codecept run acceptance
```

Get error:

```
[Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException]                                                                        
  unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally                                                                     
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 4.4.0-92-generic x86_64)
```

How solve issue with chromedriver? How find solution? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Adding "no-sandbox" and "headless" parameter to chromeOptions section did the trick for me
change your acceptance.suite.yml like this

```html
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
      - WebDriver:
            url: 'http://localhost/'
            window_size: false # disabled in ChromeDriver
            port: 9515
            browser: chrome
            capabilities:
              chromeOptions:
                args: [ "no-sandbox", "headless", "disable-gpu" ]
      - \Helper\Acceptance        
    config:
```